# Keras fails to set dynamic shape of layer properly

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using `keras==2.0.8` with `tensorflow==1.3.0` backend.
Here is the example which I am confused with:

```python
from keras.layers import Input, Reshape, Conv2DTranspose

x = Input((5000,))
y = Reshape((25, 25, 8))(x)
y = Conv2DTranspose(10, 5, padding='same', strides=2)(y)
print(y)
```

It's just part of my model and after these lines I use `y` in some tensorflow operations, but code above prints node of shape `(?, ?, ?, 10)`. I have no idea why TF cannot deduce height and width of resulting tensor statically. (I know that keras can, but I want TF node with proper shape)

Comment: what exactly is your question and desired result?

Comment: I expect that shape of the output node would be like `(?, 50, 50, 10)`, like the shape of the output of last keras layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use these tensorflow operations in a keras model, you have to use them inside `Lambda` layers.

In the function you create for the lambda layer, you can use the given tensor normally. Unless you have a very specific reason for tensorflow to have this fixed size explicit, there won't be any problem. Is there any special need that demands you to have the tensorflow tensor with explicit shape?

In Keras, you can always use `K.shape()` in a keras tensor to get its shape. Many [keras backend](https://keras.io/backend/) functions can take this shape (mostly with tensorflow) as input. If you can use the keras backend functions instead of pure tensorflow functions, your code may be portable to other backends later.

Example of function:

```
def tensorflowPart(x):

    #do tensorflow operations with the tensor x

    shape = K.shape(x) #use the shape of the tensor, as a tensor  

    #more tensorflow operations

    return result
```

Use the lambda layer in your model:

```
y = Lambda(tensorflowPart)(y)
```